# Kubectl Ingress | 404 Not Found posts.com/posts

Tags: node.js, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

My Ingress-srv.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /posts
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: posts-clusterip-srv
                port:
                  number: 4000
```

[image: Some information about my services, deployments and pods]

And also my host file is like that:

```
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 posts.com
```

TCP:80

[image: 80 port]

In the end, I got "GET http://posts.com/posts 404 (Not Found)" error, I checked step by step but didn't see my fault.

[image: posts files]

Comment: please don't use images when of text when you could paste the test directly. Images may not outlive questions and it makes it more difficult for others to reference the text.

Comment: Your question would benefit from showing some of your debugging. Can you access the endpoint via the service's NodePort (`localhost:32352`)? How about using your local DNS name (`posts.com:32352`)? If so, then it's possible the Ingress (Nginx) is configured incorrectly? Can you access some default Ingress using Nginx (there's usually one in the documentation)